# Fatal error: Couldn't find Common-Currency.json in main bundle swiftui

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

Unable to call the .Json file getting  "Fatal error: Couldn't find Common-Currency.json in main bundle". My json file is inside another xcodeproject . How can I access the "Common-Currency.json" file:

```
final class CurrencyModelData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var currencies: [CurrencyModel] = load("Common-Currency.json")
    
}
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
   
    
    let data: Data

        guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
        }

        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Looks like the file is in different package and not in the main app. Try Bundle.module instead or some init in Bundle to get the correct Bundle instance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Bundle.main` will always refer to the main executing code's bundle. Although it's a handy shortcut in most uses, it falls down here.

There are a few ways to get access to the specific bundle you needed, but I've found the most reliable for situations like this is to use a given class within the same bundle in the initializer. For example:

```swift
let bundle = Bundle(for: CurrencyModelData.self)
```

For this to work, the class has to be visible at the calling point (so it needs to be declared `public` rather than `internal` or `private`). You also can't use `struct` or other value types – it has to be a class.